# JS find key value pair in encapsulated object

Tags: javascript, object, encapsulation

I have a big problem and I need your help.

I have a object like this:

```
{
    folder1: {
        folderid: 1,
        files: {
            name: "yeah.txt"
        },
        folder2: {
            folderid: 2
            folder3: {
                folderid: 3
            }
        }
    },
    folder4: {
        folderid: 4
    }
}
```

and I want to search for the key "folderid = 3" and find the object.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Kind regards and thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to a more generalised solution, that supports multiple properties check:

```
    function search(obj, properties){
        if(Object.keys(properties).every(function(key){
            return obj[key] === properties[key];
        })) {
            return obj;
        } else {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
                var child = obj[key];
                if(child !== null && typeof child === 'object'){                
                    return search(child, properties);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dzs1orbw/

Comment: @Hendrik if you think this answer your question can you mark it as answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/L5b07bt6/

```
var obj = {
    folder1: {
        folderid: 1,
        files: {
            name: "yeah.txt"
        },
        folder2: {
            folderid: 2,
            folder3: {
                folderid: 3,
                caption: "I got it!"
            }
        }
    },
    folder4: {
        folderid: 4
    }
};

function find(root, id) {
    if (root.folderid == id) return root;
    if (typeof root !== 'object') return null;
    var key, val;
    for (key in root) {
        val = find(root[key], id);
        if (val != null) return val;
    }
    return null;
}

var result = find(obj, 3);
if (!result) alert("Not found!");
else alert("Found: " + result.caption);
```

Answer (score 1):

and here another one:

```
function findByKey (object, searchKey){
    if(typeof object !== 'object'){
        return false;
    }

    for(var key in object){
        if(object[key] === searchKey){
            return object;
        } else {
            if(typeof (object[key] === 'object')){
                var result = findByKey(object[key], searchKey);
                if(result){
                    return result;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattposch/ebmd8xtk/